# How to create an after delete trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create an AFTER DELETE trigger on the professor table, when ProfessorName/Program gets deleted it will insert the deleted into the table professor_audit_trail

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trg_Delprofessor 
    ON `lab7`.`professor` 
    AFTER DELETE AS 
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO professor_audit_trail 
    SELECT `professor`.`ProfessorName`, `professor`.`ProfessorProgram` 
    FROM Deleted 
    end;
```

Table: `professor`

Columns:

```
ProfessorName
ProfessorProgram
```

Table: `professor_audit_trail`

it outputs a 1064 error in your syntax

Comment: Please add the ENTIRE error message output in the question.

Comment: Please give a clear information about the error

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to create a Trigger on MySQL might be difference to other sql servers.
Right syntax should be:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_Delprofessor` 
AFTER DELETE ON `lab7`.`professor` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO professor_audit_trail(`ProfessorName`, `ProfessorProgram`) 
    values (old.ProfessorName, old.ProfessorProgram);
END $$
delimiter ;
```

For more information [MySQL TRIGGER SYNTAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Single-statement trigger does not need in BEGIN-END and delimiter reassign.